# Understanding the derivation of automatic relevance determination

Tags: probability, statistics, bayesian

I'm studying about automatic relevance determination from [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.651.8603&rep=rep1&type=pdf) (see pages 2-3) and I have problem in understanding the following part (on page 3 of the paper):

> The posterior probability over all the unknown parameters, given the
>   data, is expressed as $P(\textbf{w}, \boldsymbol\alpha,
>  \sigma^2|\textbf{t})$. We are trying to find the $\textbf{w},
>  \boldsymbol\alpha$ and $\sigma^2$ which maximise this posterior
>   probability. We can decompose the posterior: $$P(\textbf{w},
>  \boldsymbol\alpha, \sigma^2|\textbf{t})= P(\textbf{w}| \textbf{t},
>  \boldsymbol\alpha, \sigma^2)P(\boldsymbol\alpha,
>  \sigma^2|\textbf{t})\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; (1.1)$$ Substituting $\beta$ for
>    $\sigma^2$ to make the maths appear less cluttered, the first part of
>    $(1.1)$ can be expressed:
>
> $$P(\textbf{w}| \textbf{t}, \boldsymbol\alpha, \beta) \sim
>  N(\textbf{m},
>  \boldsymbol\Sigma)\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;
>  (1.2)$$ where the mean $\textbf{m}$ and the covariance
>    $\boldsymbol\Sigma$ are given by: $$\textbf{m} =
>  \beta\boldsymbol\Sigma\boldsymbol\Phi^T\textbf{t}\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;
>  (1.3)$$
>    $$\boldsymbol\Sigma=(\textbf{A}+\beta\boldsymbol\Phi^T\boldsymbol\Phi)^{-1}
>  \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;
>  (1.4)$$ and $\textbf{A} = diag(\boldsymbol\alpha)$. The method for
>   arriving at $(1.2), (1.3)$ and $(1.4)$, relating to conditional
>   Gaussian distributions, lies outside the scope of this document.

What I'm interested in, is how the $(1.2), (1.3)$ and $(1.4)$ are derived.

**My question is: How does one explicitly arrive into $(1.2), (1.3)$ and $(1.4)$? Any references?**

You can find all the details from the link I provided, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answers to my questions can be found from the book:

[Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning.](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387310732)

Look in the sections dealing with multivariate Gaussian distributions.